# Worksheet change and worksheet selection change slowing down my file

Tags: vba, excel

I have a file that i use as database. It has the records and in the row 1 several cells used as buttons, (open folder, copy text, send mail, ecc.) At any change on any column of any record the file register the time in one column in order to have the last change of that record. It also change the color of the row if that row is selected.
Here an image:
[image: The first buttons are just for email. "Aggiorna tutto" button do a code to refresh the database saving and changing some records from one worksheet to another depending on status, folder button is for open the folder of that specific person on server; mail button is to open an outlook message for that specific record, H1 and I1 are just text that are ready to copy and J1 and K1 are the paths for open directly the files related to that record]

The first buttons are just to send an specific email. "Aggiorna tutto" button do a code to refresh the database saving and changing some records from one worksheet to another depending on status, folder button is for open the folder of that specific person on server; mail button is to open an outlook message for that specific record, H1 and I1 are just text that are ready to copy and J1 and K1 are the paths for open directly the files related to that record.

My problem is that it is very slow to navigate trough the cells. Here my code in the worksheet:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
'This code is to register the date and time of any change in any column in every record. This in order to have only the last change of that record.
Select Case Target.Column
    Case 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40
Application.EnableEvents = False
Cells(Target.Row, 25).Value = Date + Time
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Select
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
 'I copy in first row the content that i need of every record that i navigate throug, except for the first rows where there are not records. The content is not visible is just used to feed formulas in H1, I1, J1 and K1 the folder and email button. 
 If ActiveCell.Row > 2 Then
 Dim rw As Long
 rw = ActiveCell.Row
 Range("z1") = "=c" & rw
 Range("b1") = "=b" & rw
 Range("c1") = "=c" & rw
 Range("d1") = "=d" & rw
 Range("e1") = "=e" & rw
 Range("f1") = "=f" & rw
 Range("q1") = "=aa" & rw
 Range("o1") = "=o" & rw
 Range("g1") = "=i" & rw
 Range("u1") = "=u" & rw
 Range("x1") = "=y" & rw



 If Application.CutCopyMode = False Then
 Application.Calculate
 End If
 End If

    If Selection.Count = 1 Then
        If Not Intersect(Target, Range("h1")) Is Nothing Then
            Call nomefile
        End If
        If Not Intersect(Target, Range("i1")) Is Nothing Then
            Call nomefile2
        End If
        If Not Intersect(Target, Range("j1")) Is Nothing Then
            Call nomefile3
        End If
        If Not Intersect(Target, Range("k1")) Is Nothing Then
            Call nomefile4
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Here the codes that are called:

```
Sub cartella()
'Open the folder of the student of the record
Dim cartella As String
If IsError(Range("i1").Value) Then
GoTo fin
Else
cartella = Range("i1")
Call Shell("explorer.exe " & cartella, vbNormalFocus)
End If
fin:
End Sub


Sub nomefile()
'copy the text to save the certificate with that specific text
Dim nomefile As String
On Error GoTo fin
nomefile = Range("h1").Value
Range("h1").Select
Selection.Copy
CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Popup nomefile, 1, "Testo copiato: "
fin:
End Sub

Sub nomefile2()
'copy the path to save that certificate on server
Dim nomefile2 As String
On Error GoTo fin
nomefile2 = Range("i1").Value
Range("i1").Select
Selection.Copy
CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Popup nomefile2, 1, "Testo copiato: "
fin:
End Sub

Sub nomefile3()
'Open the file previously saved. If the file does not exit open the student's folder
Dim nomefile3 As String
On Error GoTo fin
nomefile3 = Range("j1").Value & ".pdf"
If Dir(nomefile3) <> "" Then
ActiveWorkbook.FollowHyperlink nomefile3
Else
cartella
End If
fin:
End Sub

Sub nomefile4()
'Open a file. If the file does not exit open the student's folder
Dim nomefile4 As String
On Error GoTo fin
nomefile4 = Range("k1").Value & ".pdf"
If Dir(nomefile4) <> "" Then
ActiveWorkbook.FollowHyperlink nomefile4
Else
cartella
End If
fin:
End Sub
```

Comment: Could you add a short explanation for how you code works, and why you made any unorthodox choices if you did?

Comment: @K00lman Thanks for your reply. I have explained a little more. I hope it is more clear now.

Answer (score 2):

You're already declaring your variables :+1:. But I'll still mention that `Option Explicit` should be turned on. From the menu at the top Tools>Options>Editor tab>Code Settings group>Require Variable Declaration needs a check mark. That will then add `Option Explicit` to every new module mandating that `Dim variableName As String` needs to be added before any variable can be used. Again, it looks like you're already doing this but it wasn't explicitly shown in your code.

---

Naming in VBA is PascalCase for Subs/Function where `TheFirstLetterOfEveryWordIsCapitalized`. Variables is camelCase where `theSecondAndSubsequentWordsAreCapitalized`.

---

For the [Select Case statement](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/Language/Reference/User-Interface-Help/select-case-statement) want to replace `1, 2, ... , 23, 24` and `26, 27, ... , 39, 40` with a range of values. 
Below it immediately apparent that 25 is intentionally omitted. All too easy to miss that 25 is not in your original code.

```
Select Case Target.Column
    Case 1 To 24, 26 To 40
```

---

In `Cells(Target.Row, 25).Value = Date + Time` you're implicitly accessing the whatever-happens-to-be-active-sheet by not qualifying your `Cells` access with a worksheet. Because the code is within a worksheets event handler you can qualify with the identifier `Me.Cells(...)`. Otherwise if you're in a standard module explicitly qualify with the sheet you want to work with `Sheet1.Cells(...)`. Always make it explicit which worksheet you want to use so there's no guessing as to your intention.

That line is also using the [Date function](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/date-function) and the [Time function](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/time-function) when you can use the [Now function](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/now-function). `Me.Cells(Target.Row, 25).Value = Now`

---

Within `Worksheet_SelectionChange` you are implicitly accessing the default member with `Range("z1") = "assignValue"`.  `Range("z1").[_Default] = "assignValue"` is what's occurring. As stated above be explicit about member access by stating `Range("z1").Value2 = "assignValue"`. Charles William already explained [TEXT vs VALUE vs VALUE2](https://fastexcel.wordpress.com/2011/11/30/text-vs-value-vs-value2-slow-text-and-how-to-avoid-it/) if you're interested.

---

You can consolidate

```
Range("b1") = "=b" & rw
Range("c1") = "=c" & rw
Range("d1") = "=d" & rw
Range("e1") = "=e" & rw
Range("f1") = "=f" & rw
```

into a single assignment

```
Me.Range("b1", "f1").Formula = "=b" & rw
```

In addition to that you can turn off `Application.EnableEvents` until the last assignment since it's overwriting the same cell. This will increase speed a bit.

```
If ActiveCell.Row > 2 Then
    Dim rw As Long
    rw = ActiveCell.Row

    Application.EnableEvents = False

    Me.Range("z1").Value2 = "=c" & rw
    Me.Range("b1", "f1").Formula = "=b" & rw
    Me.Range("q1").Value2 = "=aa" & rw
    Me.Range("o1").Value2 = "=o" & rw
    Me.Range("g1").Value2 = "=i" & rw
    Me.Range("u1").Value2 = "=u" & rw

    Application.EnableEvents = True

    Me.Range("x1").Value2 = "=y" & rw

    If Application.CutCopyMode = False Then
        Application.Calculate
    End If
End If
```

---

The [Call statement](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/Language/Reference/User-Interface-Help/call-statement) isn't needed. It's there for legacy purposes.

---

You can conosolidate `nomefile` and `nomefile2` by paramaterizing the Sub. This is because only "h1" and "i1" are different. Refactor your code so that it accepts the arguments you need. Below you're supplying the `singleCell` variable which describes what you require of it along with how long you want the popup to display for. You can keep the Sub within the same code behind for the worksheet since, as far Is I can tell, its working on the same sheet. This goes back to qualifying your Range references to make it explicitly clear which sheet they come from.

You also don't need or want to `Range(...).Select` followed by `Selection.Copy`. [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba) answered this already.

```
Private Sub DisplayPopupForCopiedCell(ByVal singleCell As Range, ByVal secondsToDisplayWindow)
    singleCell.Copy
    CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Popup singleCell.Value2, secondsToDisplayWindow, "Testo copiato: "
End Sub
```

Now when you need to use it `DisplayPopupForCopiedCell Me.Range("h1"), 1` and `DisplayPopupForCopiedCell Me.Range("i1"), 1` are used. This eliminates copied code and when you have to make a change you only need to do so in a single location.

Do the same for `nomefile3` and `nomefile4`

---

The Sub for Cartella has no need for the label `fin:`. Replace that with the Exit statement. Also you can rename the sub. Forgiveness on my lack of Italian but a rough tranlsate results in `AprireCartellaDeiStudenti`.

```
Public Sub OpenStudentRecordFolder(ByVal folderPath As String)
    If IsError(folderPath) Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Shell "explorer.exe " & folderPath, vbNormalFocus
End Sub
```

---

The static cell references "h1", "i1" are ticking time bombs and will break if the cells are shifted by adding a row above or column to the left. Using a named range so that you have `Sheet1.Range("StudentRecordFolder")` or `Sheet1.Range("CartellaRegistrazioneStudente")` won't break with a shifting cell.

---

The above will help clarify your code. Ultimately I'm not sure how much faster it will make it.